# How can i count the elements in cypress?

Tags: javascript, random, count, find, cypress

How can i count the elements so that later use this number in random selection in cypress?
I have this code:

> ```
> > `<table class="authors-rating">` 
>   > `<thead>`
>    > `<tr>…</tr>`
>   > `</thead>`
> > `<tbody>`
>    > `<tr>…</tr>`
>    > `<tr>…</tr>`
>    > `<tr>…</tr>`
>    > `<tr>…</tr>`
>    > `<tr>…</tr>`
>    > `<tr>…</tr>`
>    > `<tr>…</tr>`
>    > `<tr>…</tr>`
>    > `<tr>…</tr>`
>    > `<tr>…</tr>`
>    > `</tbody>`
> >`</table>`
> ```

I need to count `<tr>…</tr>` from `<tbody>` and use this number for random selection. Because the quantity of `<tr>…</tr>` changes i can't use `const x = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (10 -1) + 1))` because the number 10 is a variable.
I try like this:

```
cy.visit("//")
cy.get('tbody').then($tbody => {
const count = $tbody.find('.tr')
const _number = (Math.floor(Math.random() * ((count -1) + 1)))
cy.get('tr').parents('tbody').eq(_number).click('left')
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I do it

```
cy.visit("//")
cy.xpath("//tbody/tr").then(($elements) => {
const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $elements.length);
cy.xpath("//table[@class='authorsrating']//tbody/tr").
eq(random).click('left')
```

Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the tr elements with querying the DOM then simply get the length property and use that.

```js
cy.get('.authors-rating tbody tr')
  .should('have.length.gt', 0)
  .its('length')
  .then(length => {
    //code to random sample
  })
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to yield an object to dynamically control your length **and** replace '.tr' with 'tr' the following way:

```
cy.get('body')
      .find('tr')
      .then(children => {
        const childrenCount = Cypress.$(children).length;
        expect(children).to.have.length(childrenCount);
    //Insert here whatever you need using childrenCount variable, for example:
       const randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * ((childrenCount -1) + 1)))
       cy.get('tr').parents('tbody').eq(randomNumber).click('left')
    });
```